# Cant install brain.js on macos

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, brain.js

I am on an m1 mac and I am trying to install brain.js, but its not wokring.

When running the `python --version` I get `Python 3.11.3`

and when running the `/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version` I get `Xcode 14.3 Build version 14E222b`

But when I run `npm i brain.js` I get the following error

> ```
> npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path /Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/gpu.js/node_modules/gl
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
> npm ERR! prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=18.15.0 runtime=node arch=arm64 libc= platform=darwin)
> npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
> npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | arm64
> npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.3 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11"
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/gpu.js/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/chaim/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/chaim/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/node-gyp',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/chaim/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/gpu.js/node_modules/gl',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
> npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
> npm ERR! /bin/sh: python: command not found
> npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'python commit_id.py check ..' returned exit status 127 while in angle/src/angle.gyp. while loading dependencies of
>      binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.5.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp"
>      "rebuild"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/chaim/developer/personal/tax-docs/node_modules/gpu.js/node_modules/gl
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS Monterey they removed python 2 which was installed by default.

You might need to install version 2 manually.

Also you can try fooling the installer into using version 3:

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python
```

Edit: can confirm this worked on my M1 box.